# Google App Engine fetch() ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
gql_query = "SELECT * FROM Dev_DB"
searchquery = ndb.gql(gql_query)

BATCH_SIZE = 1
results, cursor, more = searchquery.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Execution of the above code is resulting in `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

The error is getting solved when I'm giving `BATCH_SIZE` value as `3` instead of `1`. But still, it then fetches only first row of data instead of all 3.

The whole function for reference:

```
def update_pose_order_db_controller(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-type']="text/html"
    self.response.out.write("<p>Hello there, Fetching from dev</p>")

    cursor_from_url = self.request.get('start_cursor')
    logging.info("Cursor in start is: {}".format(cursor_from_url))

    gql_query = "SELECT * FROM Dev_DB"
    searchquery = ndb.gql(gql_query)

    if cursor_from_url:
        cursor_from_url = Cursor(urlsafe=cursor_from_url)
        BATCH_SIZE = 2
        results, cursor, more = searchquery.fetch(BATCH_SIZE, start_cursor = cursor_from_url)
    else:
        BATCH_SIZE = 1
        results, cursor, more = searchquery.fetch(BATCH_SIZE)

    self.response.write(results.ans_list)
```

The problem occurs in the `else` part because, at the start, the cursor is empty. Any value for `BATCH_SIZE` >= 3 works. The code never went to `if` part because the initial fetching is not getting successful and hence the cursor is not getting set to the URL as a parameter.

I'm new to the Google App Engine. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `fetch()` instead of `fetch_page()`. `fetch` is for **DB** and `fetch_page()` is for **NDB**.